# Qual critério de avaliação de uma pergunta?

Tags: suporte

Antigamente, assim que fiz o cadastro no Stackoverflow, entrava somente para obter respostas para minhas situações de desespero. Nesse tempo todo de registro, só entrava mesmo para suprir minhas necessidades.

Pois então, hoje meu pensamento mudou, pois quero muito mais ajudar as pessoas com meu amadurecimento, considerando que quando faço perguntas acabo ajudando também outras pessoas. Eu já li bastante sobre as regras do SObr, porém algumas coisas ainda não me esclareceu totalmente. Daí então me deparei na seguinte situação. Nessa seguinte pergunta, *[Mensagem de erro: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: package not installed?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/149371/mensagem-de-erro-java-lang-illegalstateexception-package-not-installed)*, foi recebida um ponto negativo (-1), e fiquei sem entender porque. Acredito que o contexto e a explicação está bem clara para o entendimento.

Será que a pergunta não está clara suficiente? Ou só de sacanagem a negativaram? Qual real critério de avaliação de uma pergunta?

Comment: Esse assunto já foi debatido aqui um bocado. O importante é entender que o critério da comunidade é... humano. Vejo perguntas e respostas relevantes com pouca pontuação, vejo perguntas de helpdesk, "faça pra mim, só quero entregar o serviço", "ache o erro" e outras do tipo com pontuação positiva (sou a favor de ajudar, mas não de "pontuar"). Felizmente, na média, ainda estamos bem por que apesar do fator humano, o sistema foi muito bem feito para equalizar essas coisas (mesmo contra "forças ocultas"). Sugestão: não se preocupe com negativo MAS sempre tente achar onde você pode melhorar.

Comment: Notar que não me prendi ao link indicado, mas sim à visão geral da coisa. Se você realmente procurar onde melhorar, e perceber que o problema não é sua postagem, ignore o -1 e parta pra próxima, pois a negativação mal faz cócegas nos seus pontos. Só que parta sempre do princípio de que pode melhorar, senão vai ficar igual alguns usuários que fazem perguntas duvidosas, e acham que o -1 é sempre "culpa dos outros", e acabam não melhorando a qualidade das postagens, gerando um "loop infinito" de -1, reclamação, e falta de qualidade. Quanto ao post, não vi motivo para -1, mas Java não é meu ramo.

Comment: @Bacco é bom sim sempre querer melhorar, porque isso no torna maduros. Isso é o que quero, ser um ser humano melhor, ajudar, adquirir experiência para poder ajudar o próximo. Quando a gente começa olhar as coisas de forma diferente, sair do padrão, se tornar um pouco mais crítico, conseguimos mais lidar com certos problemas, que é o de não importar com coisas supérfluas. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento! Abraços.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uma coisa que ainda não entendeu é que aqui é o SOpt. É o Stack Overflow em Português e não Stack Overflow do Brasil.
Dito isto...

O critério de voto é e cada um. Há a ideia de que o negativo só deva ser dado se a postagem não é útil. Em geral em respostas isso é mais quando a resposta está errada e em perguntas é se não houve pesquisa prévia ou está uma bagunça e não vai "dar em nada". Mas o julgamento é individual. Eu posso achar uma coisa e outra pessoa achar o oposto. É difícil afirmar que o voto foi dado errado. Eu posso dar uma opinião, mas ela será apenas a minha opinião e de mais ninguém. O real critério só a pessoa pode dizer e parece que ela não quis dizer, o que é um direito dela.

Então é difícil poder afirmar que votaram por sacanagem. Isso acontece, mas é raro. O que eu vejo mais é critérios que discordo.

Vejo muito voto positivo em coisa ruim e "muito" voto negativo em coisa boa.

Vejo muito positivo para "incentivar o novato", porque a pessoa gosta do assunto, porque tem curiosidade para ver aquilo, desconhece o assunto e não sabe que está errado. A pessoa não avalia se o conteúdo tem problemas ou não. Especialmente em perguntas ela não quer saber se dá para responder aqui, se foi bem feita.

Os negativos em coisa boa são por estratégia, vingança, desconhecimento do certo, discordância, impaciência ou outros motivos assim. Nenhum deles deveria ocorrer, mas não é fácil eliminá-los ou tomar providências.

Algumas pessoas consideram que certas perguntas não deveriam ser feitas e negativam. Pode ser correto. Mas pode ser só um gosto da pessoa.

Algumas pessoas negativam porque não podem votar para fechar.

## Sua pergunta

Tem gente que acha que esse tipo de coisa é só consultar o manual. Pra mim a pergunta vai além de saber o que é o erro. E mesmo que fosse só isso acho que ela não mereceria -1. O título pode ter chamado o voto. Não estou justificando, mas acho que tem gente que se apega a isso.

Tem gente que vê três interrogações e acha que a pergunta é ampla. O que acho que não é, tudo ali está relacionado e cabe na mesma resposta.

Alguém pode não ter entendido o problema e achar que não está clara. Eu não entendo do assunto e achei clara. Não sei como resolver, ou mesmo se dá para resolver só com isso, mas a pergunta está bem feita para os meus padrões, que são altos. Pode ser que alguém que saiba mais achou que faltam informações. O ideal seria avisar, se for isso.

Acho que para o tipo de pergunta ela está acima da média.

Eu só negativaria por ter formatado o *crash* como se fosse um código :P :D Então ganhou +1, mas não vai acostumando :)

## Conclusão

Não se preocupe demais com isso, faz parte. Eu recebo um monte de negativo que não entendo o porquê.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento Bigown! O Stackoverflow precisa mesmo de pessoas maduras como você, que gosta sempre de acrescentar e não rivalidar menosprezando. Vou seguir o seu conselho e fazer minha parte. Grande abraço.

Comment: Negativar por não ter feito pesquisa prévia é relativo, pode ser ou não um problema para a pergunta, além de que nada impede de fazer uma pergunta que já se saiba a resposta.

Comment: @Math eu concordo, mas tem gente que vota roboticamente, como você sabe.